# python nesting loops

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying perform a nested loop to combine data into a line by using matched MAC Addresses in both files.

I am able to pull the loop fine without the regex, however, when using the search regex below, it will only loop through the MAC_Lines once and print the correct results using the first entry in the MAC_Lines and stop. I'm unsure how to make the MAC_Lines go to the next line and repeat the process for all of the entries in the MAC_Lines.

```
try:
    for mac in MAC_Lines:
        MAC_address = re.search(r'([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}', mac, re.I)
        MAC_address_final = MAC_address.group()
        for arp in ARP_Lines:
            ARP_address = re.search(r'([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}', arp, re.I)
            ARP_address_final = ARP_address.group()
            if MAC_address_final == ARP_address_final:
                print mac + arp
            continue

 except Exception:
    print 'completed.'
```

Results:

```
13,64,00:0c:29:36:9f:02,giga-swx 0/213,172.20.13.70, 00:0c:29:36:9f:02, vlan 64
```

completed.

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your input data, and your desired output?

Comment: Note that alternations inside classes are suspicious `[:|\-]` in that they are just literal bars.

Comment: Also, for consistency, a better way to do a regex is something like this `[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?=([:-]))(?:\1[a-fA-F0-9]{2}){5}`

Comment: I don't think you need that `continue`. Otherwise, it should work ok. The outer loop `for mac in MAC_Lines:` should just get the next line. Print the line just to be sure. The inner loop `for arp in ARP_Lines:` should reset to the first element on each pass of the outer loop. I would _validate_ the search though, to be sure it actually found something.

Comment: Also, if you are using the _case insensitive option_, the class for the hex can just be `[a-f0-9]`.

Comment: input file 1:
13,64,  00:0c:29:36:9f:02,giga-swx 0/2
13,64,  00:23:24:75:82:f7, swx 0/17
13,64,  00:23:24:c6:8a:ce, swx 0/18


input file 2:
13,172.20.13.70,00:0C:29:36:9F:02,vlan 64
13,172.20.13.85,00:23:24:75:82:F7,vlan 64
13,172.20.13.90,00:23:24:C6:8A:CE,vlan 64
20,172.20.20.20,64:EB:8C:FB:BF:B5,vlan 100

expected result:
13,64,  00:0c:29:36:9f:02,giga-swx 0/2, 13,172.20.13.70,00:0C:29:36:9F:02,vlan 64
13,64,  00:23:24:75:82:f7, swx 0/17, 13,172.20.13.85,00:23:24:75:82:F7,vlan 64

Comment: When omitting the arp loop, the mac loop does go through all the mac addresses. When I do the arp loop by itself it gets all of the results, so both loops do work separately. I just have the issue when trying to get the arp loop to work with the second mac entry and so on.  Thanks for the help on the regex.

Comment: As a test, I'd try both loops together printing each line in each loop for a test. If that works, then the problem is in this statement `if MAC_address_final == ARP_address_final:` Since you are matching with 2 delimiters `[:-]` it could be one line has `aa:bb:cc...` and the other `aa-bb-cc..` etc...

Comment: with open('MAC_List.txt', 'r') as read0:
    for items0 in read0:
        MAC_address = re.search(r'([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}', items0, re.I)
        if MAC_address:
            mac_addy = MAC_address.group().upper()

        with open('ARP_List.txt', 'r') as read1:
            for items1 in read1:
                ARP_address = re.search(r'([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}', items1, re.I)
                if ARP_address:
                    arp_addy = ARP_address.group()

                if mac_addy == arp_addy:
                    print(items0.strip() + ' ' + items1.strip())

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the issue was how I opened the file. I should have used the 'open':'as' keywords when opening both files to allow the files to properly close and reopen for the next loop. Below is the code I was looking for.

Below is the code:

```
with open('MAC_List.txt', 'r') as read0:for items0 in read0:
    MAC_address = re.search(r'([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}', items0, re.I)
    if MAC_address:
        mac_addy = MAC_address.group().upper()                                              
    with open('ARP_List.txt', 'r') as read1:
        for items1 in read1:
            ARP_address = re.search(r'([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}', items1, re.I)
            if ARP_address:
                arp_addy = ARP_address.group()

            if mac_addy == arp_addy:
                print(items0.strip() + ' ' + items1.strip())
```